# Problem using thmtools, hyperref and showkeys all together

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, incompatibility, thmtools, showkeys

When I use `\eqref` (from `amsmath`) in the optional argument to the `proof` environment (from `amsthm`) and the three packages `thmtools`, `hyperref`, and `showkeys` are loaded, TeX runs into an infinite loop.  Here is a minimal failing example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm} 
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{showkeys}   

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2 
\label{simple}
\end{equation}

\begin{proof}[Proof of~\eqref{simple}]
Count on your fingers.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000].
\@x@protect #1\fi #2#3->
                    \fi \protect #1
l.14 \begin{proof}[Proof of~\eqref{simple}]

No pages of output.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: `\protect\eqref`

Comment: Wow.  It's that simple.  Amazing how the problem surfaces only with a strange combination of packages and circumstances.  I guess that's the unpredictability of using fragile commands in moving arguments.

Comment: @daleif an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\eqref` is not robust, thus in some cases it needs protection, that is `\protect\eqref`